# A simple inequality in probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need to prove this seemingly simple inequality. If $X$ and $Y$ are iid discrete random variables, how does one prove that

$$2P(|X-Y|=0)\ge P(|X-Y|=x)$$ where $x$ is any other positive integer.

Is there any analogous result in the continuous case?

Comment: This inequality can't be true. Take $X$ to be $1$ with probability $1$. And $Y$ to be $2$ with probability $1$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov $X$ and $Y$ are supposed to have the same law.

Comment: Silly me, I read over the iid of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_k:=P(X=k)=P(Y=k)$. We have 
\begin{align*}
P(|X-Y|=x)&= P(X-Y=x)+P(Y-X=x)\\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0}P(Y=k)P(X=x+k)+\sum_{k\geq 0}P(X=k)P(Y=x+k)\\
&=2\sum_{k\geq 0}a_ka_{x+k}\\
&\leq 2\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}a_k^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}a_{h+k}^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq 2\sum_{k\geq 0}a_k^2\\
&=2P(X=Y).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks Davide. A couple of questions - One (silly): What is the reason for the first inequality? I can't see any other condition for $|X-Y|=x$. Two: Anyway one could extend this for the continuous case? It would be great if you can add that as well...

Comment: For the first, write the event $\{|X-Y|=k\}$ as the event $(\{|X-Y|=k\}\cap (X\geq Y))\cup (\{|X-Y|=k\}\cap (X\leq Y))\subset \{X-Y=k\}\cup\{Y-X=k\}$. For the continuous case, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $P(X=Y)=0$.

Comment: I think that his first question was: "why is there an inequality instead of an equality?" (because there is equality, since $x$ is positive).

Comment: @Thomine: Do you mean to say there ought to be an equality in the first equation?

Comment: @Davide: I was envisaging something like $f_Z(z)\le 2f_Z(0)$, where $Z=X-Y$. Isn't that true?

Comment: The density $f_Z$ is only defined almost everywhere, so what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @D.Thomine The inequality is needed when $x=0$.

Comment: @Didier Pau: The original question said "where x is any other positive integer", so I assumed $x$ was non-zero. Not that it really matters, anyway.

Comment: @D.Thomine: I see.